# Add or remove an object from an object in redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the `react-redux` reducer, Here I have an object which is coming as a response from an API call.

So, I have saved it in a state as a `jobList`. Now, The response object that I got is like this:

```
{
   "jdId":"5c987c171251350001330f72",
   "userName":"abc",
   "location":{
      "weightage":1,
      "quickWeightage":1,
      "criteria":"abcc"
   },
   "mustHaveSkills":{
      "technologies":[
         {
            "weightage":0.5,
            "quickWeightage":1,
            "criteria":"OOPS"
         },
         {
            "weightage":0.5,
            "quickWeightage":1,
            "criteria":"OOPS"
         }
      ],
      "functionalSkills":[
         {
            "weightage":0.5,
            "quickWeightage":1,
            "criteria":"OOPS"
         },
         {
            "weightage":0.5,
            "quickWeightage":1,
            "criteria":"OOPS"
         },
         {
            "weightage":0.5,
            "quickWeightage":1,
            "criteria":"OOPS"
         },

      ]
   },
   "shouldHaveSkills":{
      "technologies":[
         {
            "weightage":0.35,
            "quickWeightage":0.7,
            "criteria":"C"
         },
         {
            "weightage":0.35,
            "quickWeightage":0.7,
            "criteria":"C"
         }
      ],
      "functionalSkills":[

      ]
   },
   "couldHaveSkills":{
      "technologies":[

      ],
      "functionalSkills":[

      ]
   },
   "goodToHaveSkills":{
      "technologies":[
         {
            "weightage":0.25,
            "quickWeightage":0.5,
            "criteria":"XAMARIN"
         }
      ],
      "functionalSkills":[

      ]
   }
}
```

Now, Here I have already written some actions which are like ,

```
export const add(obj, type) {   
    return {
       type: ADD_DATA,
       payload: obj
    }
}
```

Now, In reducer:

```
 case ADD_DATE : {

// Here I want to update this object which is having a an object for the 
 //mustHaveSkills which is an key with array of objects. and I want to add that new object in this array. I also have the type as this key has two arrays in it which to be updated.
}
```

Now, Here,I am passing an object to be updated as a

```
{
  "weightage": 0.5,
  "quickWeightage": 1,
  "criteria": "OOPS"
}
```

type as a `Technology` and I have written seperate actions for the four keys that needs to be updated. So, for example I need to update the `mustHaveSkills`.

So, Now How can I update that particular object in the reducer state ?
Any help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to update a particular key based on result? And how are you updating objects in reducer? Can you please share sample reducer code.

Comment: Actually I want to add an new obj in the  mustHaveSkills  which has two array , In that to the technologies array need to add a this new obj

Comment: That is want I want to do, update an object which is having mustHaveSkills as a key in that there are two prop technologies and functionalSkills, Here in this I have the type in param so I want to add this newly obj in the technologies

Comment: I have created a sample codesandbox for assigning values based on key, please refer this https://codesandbox.io/s/k5992qvm13

Comment: actually , I will have empty object as a initial State and then once response comes I will get that response.

Comment: Updated the sandbox with default state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the `technologies` section of `mustHaveSkills` then you can do as

```
case ADD_DATA: 

    return {
        ...state,
        mustHaveSkills: {
            ...state.mustHaveSkills,
            technologies: [...mustHaveSkills.technologies, action.payload],
        }
    }
```

Considering the fact that `action.payload` contains this data

```
{
    "weightage": 0.5,
    "quickWeightage": 1,
    "criteria": "OOPS"
}
```

And also with the assumption that `state` object structure is like the response object you have posted.

Comment: yes the structure is exact same. I have one dout that so here I  don't have to declare mustHaveSkills this as a initial state right ?

Comment: will it update the whole object ? I mean it will be a with the new added value right ?

Comment: if you initial state don't contain `must HaveSkills` then it will break at this line `...state.mustHaveSkills` so you need to declare it.Other ways are there to handle it

Comment: Yes, it will create a new object with the new added value.

Comment: yes, that is what I was saying , I actually don't want to defined this things

Comment: because int his there are multiple things that needs to be changed in this objects

Comment: one way is you can create multiple actions or else you can pass in the payload which key needs to be updated like if you want to update the `technologies` of `mustHaveSkills` then pass an object as `{objectToAdd, 'mustHaveSkills', 'technologies`'}

Comment: yes that I can do but what about if I don't initialize this things as this are going to come in an object which is going to come from server response and that whole I am assing it in the reducer

Comment: The whole response object will come from server or only the skill to add??

Comment: whole response object and that skill to be added is  I have to add from front-end by making that kind of object

Comment: is there any option ?